# Android Network Operations Architecture

Tags: java, android, json, rest, http

I am an aspiring Android Developer, I have faced many issues in integrating my REST apis in Android. Existing solutions like Retrofit, volley are very generic.

I have been working on creating a generic framework for REST apis. Need  help to complete it. I have configured components as follows:

Assumptions: Json data type as request body and json data type as request response

1. CentralCommandClass (activities will access this class to perform network operations with callback method as parameter)
2. API class extends IntentService (static functions for get, post, put  etc to start service with different parameters)
3. MyHttpRequest (having execute method to open url connection and gets response from server)

My questions are as follows:

1. Does this approach has any downside?
2. There is a requirement to fire few requests only after one specific request has been fired, how do I handle this case?